# Equivalent form of the Whitehead problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and consider the following statement.

> $M$ is projective whenever the obvious group map $\tau:
> \text{Hom}_R(M, R) \to \text{Hom}_R(M, {R}/{I})$ is surjective for any
>   ideal $I\subset R$.

I have read that when $R = \mathbb{Z}$, determining the truth of this statement is equivalent to deciding the Whitehead problem, which asks whether or not the abelian group $M$ must be free so long as every group extension of $M$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.

I know that being free is equivalent to being projective for abelian groups. But why is the surjectivity of $\tau$ equivalent to the condition that $\text{Ext}(M, \mathbb{Z}) =0$? I don't see how the fact that $\tau$ is surjective implies that any such extension splits.

I may be missing something obvious, but could someone please explain?

Here is one reference for what I am talking about.

[Google book page.](https://books.google.com/books?id=SLs6DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT96&lpg=PT96&dq=whitehead%20problem%20%22Baer%20criterion%22&source=bl&ots=G7OBkTUMOY&sig=ACfU3U3-q9MiKRtOqGW3iHPb9WHaaTIyWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNvcjy2vvfAhVJm-AKHZ7yAgo4ChDoATAAegQIABAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect: surjectivity of $\tau$ is strictly weaker than  $\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$.  Specifically, surjectivity of $\tau$ is instead equivalent to  $\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ being torsion-free.  The statement that you quoted is not equivalent to Whitehead's problem for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and in fact is provably false for $R=\mathbb{Z}$.  For instance, if $M=\mathbb{Q}$, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}/I)=0$ for any ideal $I\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$, so $\tau$ is trivially always surjective, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective.

Here's how you prove that surjectivity of $\tau$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ being torsion free.  Note that for any $I\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, we have a long exact sequence $$0\to \operatorname{Hom}(M,I)\to\operatorname{Hom}(M,\mathbb{Z})\stackrel{\tau}\to\operatorname{Hom}(M,\mathbb{Z}/I)\stackrel{\delta}\to\operatorname{Ext}(M,I)\stackrel{f}\to\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})\to\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z}/I)\to 0.$$

In particular, we see that $\tau$ is surjective iff $\delta=0$ iff $f$ is injective.  Note moreover that if $I$ is nontrivial, then $I=n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n>0$ and so we can identify $f$ with the multiplication by $n$ map $\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})\to\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})$.  So, $\tau$ is surjective for $I=n\mathbb{Z}$ iff $\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ has no $n$-torsion.  We conclude that $\tau$ is surjective for all $I$ iff $\operatorname{Ext}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Thank you, but I keep reading that my quoted statement is the dual of Baer's criterion for injective modules and that this reduces to the Whitehead problem for $R= \mathbb{Z}$. Do you have any idea what the correct version of this claim is supposed to look like?

Comment: Where are you reading that?  I don't think there's any sense in which the Whitehead problem is literally dual to Baer's criterion, though they are certainly related.

Comment: I've given the link of one reference in my OP. But you are certainly right.

Comment: I think it's simply an error in that text where the authors were a bit over-eager to fit a remark on Whitehead's problem into their narrative.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In fact, the correct formulation is much more delicate. It seems to be known as "Faith's problem on $R$-projectivity" if you're interested.